# How to change the format of the date & time displayed in top panel?

Tags: indicator

By default date and time is displayed by the clock applet on the top right of the gnome desktop in Ubuntu. For me this displays something like "Tue Aug 3, 19:45". I would like to change it to make the date terser and to include e.g., ISO week number - to something like 03/08-19:45-W31.2

Is there anyway I can specify a "format string" for how the date-time is displayed ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Open [`gconf-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) by pressing <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and typing `gconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `apps -> panel -> applets`.
3. Look for your applet. In my case it is called `applet_3`, on another computer its name is `clock_0`. Maybe a good way is to search (<kbd>Strg+f</kbd> or for US keyboards <kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd>, activate both fields in the search menu) for `ClockApplet` (case *must* match).
4. Go to `prefs`. Change the value of `format` to `custom` and change `custom_format` to whatever you like. The syntax comes from [`strftime()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strftime/).
5. The format will immediately change if you enter some values.

Note: This option will not work in 10.10's netbook edition, [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14458/how-do-i-get-the-clock-to-show-the-date) for a solution.

Comment: WoW! It works. This is awesome. Too good. Thanks qbi for the detailed response.

Comment: 1 minor point. The Strg key is the Ctrl key in USA keyboards so Strg+F results in "Find" being invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer and added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Is it only for me or does the 'Copy Date' function (if you right-click on the Clock-applet) still delivers the default date-format if you edit the shown date-format?

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in looking at some examples other people have done with the same process. See: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/gnome-panel-clock-themes.html
I used the first one and couldn't be happier, but now that you mentioned week number, I need that too.

Comment: Thanks. Inspiring Indeed. Of course I shd have searched OMG! Ubuntu! first :-). Anyway I made a mod to the first one in that article for including the week number & day ([%v.%u]). Modified version at http://pastebin.com/rRAbqBWm
There are 2 config strings - first one compacts date display and adds week.day. Second one also modifies text color (to match the default text panel text color in Ambiance Theme)  and increases font size so that I could read it :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my custom time format.... `<sup> <span font_desc="Droid Sans 14"  color="green"> %a  %b %d </span> <span font_desc="Droid Sans 20" weight="Bold" color="green"  >%l:%M %p</span></sup>` ....Works well with a dark panel color. Change the color code to suit your needs.

[image]