# I want my panel clock to be "digital" (2011-01-01). Is there a setting, or another clock?

Tags: panel, clock, time, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the format of the date & time displayed in top panel ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-date-time-displayed-in-top-panel)

I've been using computers for too long. The "human" display of the date/time in the panel looks a bit strange to me these days.

I am quite happy with the more functional and sortable digits-and-dots-and-dashes approach.  Give me YYYY-MM-DD hh.nn.ss  any day! (with leading zeroes)

I am a recent refugee from land of Windows, where one consolation was a nice tray clock `(TClockEx)`which had free-form layouts for both the tray-display and the copy-to-clipboard.

Although I like the general features of the standard-issue clock, I really do want a free-form digital clock (preferably with clipboard-out)... and my calendar week starts on Monday (not Sunday, as per the panel-clock)

I often need a sortable digital date/time prefix for file names. The clock is handy for this.

Can the standard Ubuntu clock do this? I couldn't find anything.
... or is there another clock which can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNOME Clock is actually very customizable once you dig into the gconf settings.

Launch `gconf-editor` from the terminal or the "Run Application" dialog (`Alt-F2`).

Navigate to `/apps/panel/applets/clock_screen0/prefs/custom_format`

[image: gconf]

Take a look at [`man strftime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man3/strftime.3posix.html) for the different variables you can use there.

You also need to set `/apps/panel/applets/clock_screen0/prefs/format` to `custom` for your changes to take effect.

Comment: Great... It seems that I need to become more attuned to this mysterious and wonderful "gconf-editor"... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with the standard Ubuntu clock.

Open the `gconf-editor` and navigate to `apps -> panel -> applets -> clock_screen0 -> prefs`. You can then set the key `custom_format` to any format you want, e.g. `%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S` should give the format you want. You also have to set the key named `format` to `custom` so that your custom format is used.

The custom format can also contain HTML formatting, so you could use something fancy like `<b>%Y-%m-%d</b> %H.%M.<span color=”#888888″>%S</span>` to display the date in bold and the seconds in grey...

Comment: Uh, actually I just realized that the question is a duplicate of: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-date-time-displayed-in-top-panel

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. It's now looking good (to me)! ... (I don't know how I missed the other answer, but I did :(