# How do I get the clock to show the date?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, gnome-panel, clock

I tried what was mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723/how-to-change-the-format-of-the-date-time-displayed-in-top-panel) to no avail. When I update the values in gconf (any of the values, not just custom and custom_format) nothing changes. Is this a netbook edition problem? Is there another clock that I should be looking for, where the changes actually are happening? I only see one clock in the panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 10.10 the tools have been changed to dconf. First install [dconf-tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dconf-tools)

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then run `dconf-editor`

Then navigate to **apps -> indicators -> datetime** and then check the "show-date" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I wish I had a few more reputation points, so I could vote this up. Sorry.

Comment: Voted it up for you as it helped deal with something that was getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 3):

there is even a more simple answer to it. Right click on the clock, and click preferences. Just check `show the date`.

[image]

Comment: This option isn't available in the 10.10 netbook edition.

Comment: In 11.04, the option is called "Time and Date Settings" and the dialog is a little different, but it's basically the same idea.  It probably has something to do with Unity?